# Xcode - @IBDesignables - Required code signing missing for X.framework

Tags: xcode, xcode-storyboard

I know similar questions has been asked before but nothing seems to work for me.

Im using CocoaPods and installing framework "X". This can be anything that can be edited directly in the Storyboard. Two examples are "MBCircularProgressBar" and "UICircularProgressRing".

Im adding it to a UIView and getting this error instantly. It messes up my storbyboard but the app is running fine.

I'm using the newest version of Xcode, newest MAC OS.

**What have i tried?**

- Deleted everything in DerivedData for Xcode
- Clean, build, refresh views ++
- Removing the problem pods and reinstalling/trying a different one
- Disabled "Automatic code signing" in "General" and set it manually to my company

Error at the moment shows :

```
Main.storyboard: error: IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status for Dashboard_UsageVC (mqT-RZ-029): dlopen(MBCircularProgressBar.framework, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    MBCircularProgressBar.framework: required code signature missing for 'MBCircularProgressBar.framework'
```

**UPDATE 23.04.2018 - Still not solved**

Still having this problem. I have gone to the extreme and fully reset my MAC. Reinstalled everything. Same problem. Even when downgrading CocoaPods to 1.4.0 and Xcode to previous version. To avoid pulling all my hair out Im now finishing the rest of the app where nothing special is needed and hoping for a magic solution for this closer to app release.

Comment: try this command `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` then build your project

Comment: As mentioned in my question this has already been done. Ref "Deleted everything in DerivedData for Xcode"

Comment: Have you tried? Refresh all views or debug selected view from editor

Answer (score 10):

It has been fixed with Cocoapods 1.5.2 (and probably 1.5.1 but I have upgrade directly from 1.5.0 to 1.5.2).

**UPDATE**

I may have spoken too fast. 
The error re-appears after a few builds.

However, this workaround seems to work *(applies to Cocoapods 1.5.x)* until the bug fix is merged:

- clean your project
- close Xcode and delete DerivedData
- open Podfile in your project , and add this:

  `post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED')
      config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED')
    end
  end`
- then in command line do a:

`pod update` or `pod install`

Sources:

- https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7606#issuecomment-381279098
- https://github.com/evgenyneu/Cosmos/issues/105
- https://github.com/Skyscanner/SkyFloatingLabelTextField/issues/201#issuecomment-381915911

Comment: Hello. Before I start pulling out my hair trying again. Is this a workaround for the 1.52 version? The reason Im asking is that I have done exactly what you're saying here with the 1.5 and 1.4 version without any success. And like you mentioned also. It seems to be working shortly before you start changing variables etc and then the error comes back again.

Comment: @Sourcey86 Hello. I only did this for Cocoapods 1.5.2 and so far it still works. Don't forget to clean your project and delete DerivedData before the pod update.

Comment: I didn't have to do the project clean or delete derived data for this to work. Just ensure that the code is placed at the very end of your pod file, after the previous last 'end' tag.

Answer (score 8):

Same bug for me.

For me, it cames after installing the last version cocoapods 1.5.0. So I downgraded it to 1.4.0 and the bug disappear.

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.4.0
```

Hoped it will helped you too.

Comment: UPDATE : Did not resolve the problem. It worked with one out of 3 pods briefly, but now Im back to the same problem again.

The one pod that worked was OK for a day until it randomly appeared again while coding in a .swift file that wasnt even related to the UI with the pod active. God I hate XCode sometimes (aka most of the time). Its taking so much time fixing annoying errors like this.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for me.When I downgrade cocoapods to 1.4.0,the problem disapper.
I am using [DownloadButton](https://github.com/PavelKatunin/DownloadButton).

Comment: refer to:https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7606#issuecomment-381279098
another way .